# How to Read a CSV file onto a Text Pane Java

Tags: java, csv, jtextpane, settext

OK SO I'm doing a project for class and I've gotten what I need to work working (For now.) What I want to do now is when I click a button a the gui it displays all the data in the Text Pane. So far all it does is print out Grades (Which I understand why) But I want it to print out what is being parsed in the CSV Files. I'm not asking for anyone to magically solve my entire code I have most of that down, I just don't know how to make the button actually display the desired results and it's making me mad because I finally got the code to do what I wanted but I can't see the results. (It works in the Console but when the .jar is run nothing is displayed.)

The Question has been answered Read comments below. Code has been removed. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't create a new `JTextPane` everytime your `JButton` was clicked. Add the pane once to the `JFrame` and in your `ActionListener` just set the value via `setText:`
2. You never set the content of your csv file to your `JTextPane` via `setText:` but you only print it out via `System.out.println("Student - " + grades[0] + " "+ grades[1] + " Grade - " + grades[2]);`

Here I made you an example. The example doesn't really base on your posted code since it would have been to much effort to look into your whole code and correct it, but it shows everything you need to do in order to make your code work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Instructor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final JTextPane textPane;
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        frame.add(textPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Read CSV");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Reset textpanes content so on every button click the new content of the read file will be displayed
                textPane.setText("");
                String fileResult = "";                 
                try {
                BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myCSV.csv"));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    //Do your logic here which information you want to parse from the csv file and which information you want to display in your textpane
                    fileResult = fileResult + "\n" +line;
                }
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.err.println("File was not found");
                }
                catch(IOException ioe) {
                    System.err.println("There was an error while reading the file");
                }
                textPane.setText(fileResult);
            }
        });
        frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

So what did I do:

1. Create `JTextpane` not in the `ActionListener` but once
2. Read the file in the `ActionListener` and provide `try` and `catch` in order to make sure there is some error handling when the file can't be found or something like this.
3. Don't print the results of the csv via `System.out.println();` but set the results to the `JTextPane` by calling the `setText:` method.

I also added a `LayoutManger` (`BorderLayout`) instead of adding the `JTextPane` and the button to the `JFrame` with `NullLayout`. This isn't part of the question but if you got time you should change this, since the `NullLayout` isn't recommended at all (`setBounds` in your code).

Comment: OK I THINK I got what you're saying for part one and have corrected that. As for Part two, what do you mean? How do I go about setting the content of csv files to the JTextPane?

Comment: I'll make you an example in a minute

Comment: I Greatly appreciate the help. I'm struggling in this class and help is hard to find.

Comment: You can also find the documentation of the method setText here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setText(java.lang.String)

Comment: OH My gosh you're a saint I got it working! Thank you so much! I'd upvote if I could but don't have the 'points' to but I'll mark as best answer! My only question now is how would I tell it to just read the first and second item of each row? Like one of my codes has grades and the second has JUST Names no grades.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean parsing the file. You already did it in your posted code. Your CSV file for example has some kind of seperator between the grade and the name. Example for one row: John Doe, 2. Then when you read the file line by line you can split the read row like       `String[] information = line.split(",");`
and in `information[0]` is "John Doe" in `information[1]` is "2" stored. So you need to write some "logic" based on your input file and how this file is formatted, then retrieve the information and then display it in the textpane.

Comment: Right I get how to parse things. And what you're saying makes sense, But as for coding I'm at a loss, Like for right now it's just 4 rows with 3 columns  as indicated in my faulty code above. This is completely different from what I coded and when I tried to re-code to get just grades[0] and grades[1] I kept getting errors BUT the code you provided helped me to get it into the box and it does print out all 3 columns. Now I just need the first two columns. I can't just state fileResults = grades[0] + grades[1]; ?

Comment: NEVER MIND I had an out of bounds error and didn't catch it! I fixed it! THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!

Comment: @ZaneH, Just use the JTextPane.read(...) method. The read(...) method is supported by all text components.